# "come home" vs "come to homes"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

From [NPR](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=267185097):

> Gino's business is a sign of the times. It's called the LED Diet. He ***comes to homes*** with a van load full of LED light bulbs - the latest in energy-efficient lighting - to help out customers like Phyllis, who are absolutely stumped by the current moment in light bulb history.

What I often see is *come home*, why does it add a word "to" in the middle of the two words?

Comment: I think these *homes* are not "his homes", it's other people's homes. In a sense it's not an uncountable noun in the phrase *come home*, but it becomes a countable noun, meaning *house(s)*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. is correct - write an answer! :)

Answer (score 5):

It's because these ***homes*** are not "his homes"; they are other people's homes.

The word *homes* used in the sentence is not the same as the one in the phrase *come home*, which is an uncountable noun. This *homes* is countable, meaning houses.

Using the verb ***come*** like this ([to move towards a place](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/come), or to arrive at a place) would need a preposition, such as, *come **to***, or *come **from***. One well-known ***come to*** phrase is the name of that Christmas song: ***[Santa Claus Is Coming to Town](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus_Is_Coming_to_Town)***. :-)